# How to filter a key word of LEFT JOIN table in SQLite 3?

Tags: sql, sqlite, left-join

This question maybe a little complex. I use a simple example to explain my question. I know these tables structure unusual. My question is about SQL command.

Example, 3 Tables:

**ParameterTable**

```
P_ID   ParaName_ID
  1        1
  2        2
  3        3
```

**ParaDescTable**

```
P_ID   ParaDesc_ID
  1        4
  2        5
  3        6
```

**LangTable**

```
String_ID    StringValue
  1          Name_Hello1
  2          Name_2
  3          Name_3
  4          Desc_TEXT1
  5          Desc_Hello2
  6          Desc_TEXT2
```

If I enter the SQL command:

```
SELECT p.* ,    
    lang0.StringValue ParaName,        
    lang1.StringValue ParaDescription

FROM ParameterTable p 
    LEFT JOIN LangTable lang0
        ON lang0.String_ID = p.ParaName_ID AND lang0.String_ID
    LEFT JOIN ParaDescTable pt
        ON pt.P_ID = p.P_ID
    LEFT JOIN LangTable lang1
        ON lang1.String_ID = pt.ParaDesc_ID AND lang0.String_ID 

WHERE  p.P_ID > 0
```

It will show as:

```
P_ID   ParaName_ID  ParaName     ParaDescription 
 1         1        Name_Hello1  Desc_Text1 
 2         2        Name_2       Desc_Hello2
 3         3        Name_3       Desc_Text3
```

I want to add a filter function, searching a key word 'Hello' in ParaName & ParaDescription column as following.

```
P_ID   ParaName_ID  ParaName     ParaDescription 
 1         1        Name_Hello1  Desc_Text1 
 2         2        Name_2       Desc_Hello2
```

How to modify the SQL command?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not to be condescending, but the solution seems rather … obvious. What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry,  I don't list a good example.  In real case,  there is an 'IN' after 'WHERE',  I can't  just add 'LIKE' after 'WHERE'.  I will modify my qurstion,  sorry about that.

Comment: Why are you using outer joins? When searching for key words, you will not find 'missing' rows anyway.

Comment: Finally, I find a method to remove 'IN' after 'WHERE' in my real case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never work with SQLite but try to use LIKE Clause

try

```
SELECT p.* ,    
    lang0.StringValue ParaName,        
    lang1.StringValue ParaDescription

FROM ParameterTable p 
    LEFT JOIN LangTable lang0
        ON lang0.String_ID = p.ParaName_ID AND lang0.String_ID
    LEFT JOIN ParaDescTable pt
        ON pt.P_ID = p.P_ID
    LEFT JOIN LangTable lang1
        ON lang1.String_ID = pt.ParaDesc_ID AND lang0.String_ID 

WHERE  p.P_ID > 0
AND (paraName LIKE '%Hello%' OR ParaDescription LIKE '%Hello%' )
```

Comment: Really appreciation. If possible, could you modify 'paramName' as 'ParaName', thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Try like this also

```
select * from (
SELECT p.* ,    
    lang0.StringValue ParaName,        
    lang1.StringValue ParaDescription

FROM ParameterTable p 
    LEFT JOIN LangTable lang0
        ON lang0.String_ID = p.ParaName_ID AND lang0.String_ID
    LEFT JOIN ParaDescTable pt
        ON pt.P_ID = p.P_ID
    LEFT JOIN LangTable lang1
        ON lang1.String_ID = pt.ParaDesc_ID AND lang0.String_ID 

WHERE  p.P_ID > 0 ) as tt where paramName LIKE '%Hello%' 
OR ParaDescription LIKE '%Hello%'
```